# Dynamic attribute values for directives

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a directive with following annotation:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'i-text-field[number-format]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
```

In the directive I get the attribute value with the input annotation

```
export class NumberFormatDirective {

@Input('number-format') format: string;
...
```

Now e.g. I can define my number format in the component like

```
<i-text-field
label='Number' hint='00000,00'
number-format='7,2'
ngControl>
</i-text-field>
```

How can I a tell the component which format to use by using a function?

```
number-format='<<function-call>>'
```

Comment: What is `number-format='<<function-call>>'`? Where is it? I can't see what the actual problem is.

Comment: I am creating a data-table and the table should tell the directive and the component which number-format to use

Comment: Have you tried  number-format='{{getCorrectFormat()}}'

Comment: What are the possible formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article on template syntax for Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html). Assuming you wrote a function called `setNumberFormat()` in your component, you could set the value of the `number-format` attribute as follows:

```
// my-component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NumberFormatDirective } from "./number-format-directive.ts";

@Component({
    directives: [NumberFormatDirective],
    template: `
        <i-text-field
            label='Number' hint='00000,00'
            number-format='{{setNumberFormat()}}'
            ngControl>
        </i-text-field>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {

    setNumberFormat(): string {
        // code to set your number format, e.g.
        return "7,2";
    }
}
```