# Passing Dynamic value for directive attribute getting undefined Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Using "@angular/core": "^5.0.1", "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1", "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1".

I have functionality like checking all the fields have a XXXqaName attribute added to it, so added a directive with @input attribute which accepts the XXXqaName

Static input like qa-name=**"matselectone"** for selector mat-select element Works Fine and XXXqaName attribute appeared in HTML template like :

[image]

```
<mat-select XXXqaName="matselectone"></mat-select> // Works fine
```

When adding **dynamic values for mat-options** like  **XXXqaName="data-{{ option.value }}"** input is not passes(i.e undefined) and XXXqaName attribute is not found in HTML template like

```
<mat-option XXXqaName="data-{{ option.value }}"></mat-option> // XXXqaName missing in HTML template only ng-reflect name is present.
```

[image]

Note: option.value is there and option value in dropdown is populated except the attribute "xxxqaName" is missing in HTML.

Directive :

```
@Directive({
     selector: `input[type="text"], mat-select, mat-option`
 })
export class QaDirective implements OnInit {

   @Input('XXXqaName') qaName: string;

   constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

   ngOnInit() { this.verifyQa();}

   verifyQa(): void {
   if (!this.qaName) {
   console.error('No "XXXqaName" provided for:',This.element.nativeElement);
   return;
   }
  }
}
```

**Directive when passing dynamic value for input attribute value remains undefined.** Is there alternative way to pass dynamic value into directive Any help would be great.

Note : Might look like [Dynamic attribute values for directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142928/dynamic-attribute-values-for-directives) but they use function in their component to manipulate input. Here it is slightly diff the attribute remains undefined.

Comment: `When inspecting html template couldn't find attribute` Of course you won't see those attributes since you're binding to property

Comment: yes cant bind property great.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fynww2?file=app/directive/qa-directive.directive.ts

Comment: I added  `@HostBinding('attr.qa-name')` front of  `@Input('qa-name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

Property bindings are not added to the DOM. 
If you want a binding to become an attribute, use the `attr.` binding

```
attr.XXXqaName="data-{{ option.value }}"
```

or

```
[attr.XXXqaName]="'data-' + option.value"
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsepal?file=app/app.component.html)

**original**

When you check the attribute it isn't yet created

Use `ngAfterViewInit()` instead

```
@Directive({
     selector: `input[type="text"], mat-select, mat-option`
 })
export class QaDirective implements OnInit {

   @Input('XXXqaName') qaName: string;

   constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.verifyQaNameAttr();
  }

   verifyQa(): void {
   if (!this.qaName) {
   console.error('No "XXXqaName" provided for:',This.element.nativeElement);
   return;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried ngAfterViewInit and reset of the lifecycle hooks still not getting but ng-reflect-XXXqaName is present.. if (!this.qaName) gets success and error gets printed with specific element.

Comment: What is "reset of the lifecycle hooks"? Can you demonstrate in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: checked with ngAfterViewInit() and then ngAfterViewInit... sure i ll make stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3daqt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html When inspecting html template couldn't find attribute

Comment: You can use `ngOnChanges` or make `qaName` a getter/setter and put the code into the setter https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-liu612?file=app/directive/qa-directive.directive.ts